# Probability of X red balls when drawing Y balls from A red and B green balls.

Tags: probability

**Background**

Ok, so I have a homework problem looking for probability distributions. So the first step is to calculate the probability of each possible result.

Specifically, I have 7 red balls and 4 green balls and am drawing 5 balls without replacement. Then I want to know the probability of getting 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 red balls.

There are various answers to similar problems, but I'm having difficulty finding a question asking about the general case, and answers with any real explanation of what's going on. I want a better way than going through a bunch of tedious crap each time, so I tried to solve this myself.

**Solution to the Specific Problem**

In my specific case, I can brute force it.

I can't possibly get 0 red balls, since there are only 4 not-red balls, so $P(\text{0 red})=0$.

$P(\text{5 red})$ is just $\frac{7_r}{7_r+4_g}$ $\cdot\frac{6_r}{6_r+4_g}$ $\cdot\frac{5_r}{5_r+4_g}$ $\cdot\frac{4_r}{4_r+4_g}$ $\cdot\frac{3_r}{3_r+4_g}$ $=\frac{7_r}{11_t}$ $\cdot\frac{6_r}{10_t}$ $\cdot\frac{5_r}{9_t}$ $\cdot\frac{4_r}{8_t}$ $\cdot\frac{3_r}{7_t}$ $=\frac{1}{22}$.

Similar math can show the probability $P(RGGGG)$ $=P(GRGGG)$ $=P(GGRGG)$ $=P(GGGRG)$ $=P(GGGGR)$ $=\frac{7\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1}{11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7}$. Since there are five ways to get one red, the total probability is $P(\text{1 red})$ $=\frac{1}{66}$.

The same concept can be used to get that $P(\text{4 red})$ $=P(\text{1 green})$ $=5\cdot P(GRRRR)$ $=5\cdot\frac{4\cdot7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4}{11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7}$ $=\frac{10}{33}$.

It's a bit more annoying with 2 and 3 balls. Now, I have to calculate the odds of every combination of two reds and three greens. However, I think the math ends up being the same. The denominator is always $11\cdot10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7$ or $\frac{11!}{6!}$ $=55440$. The numerator for the first red is 7, the second is 6, the third is 5. The numerator for green is 4, 3, 2.

So $P(RRGGG)$ $=P($any specific permutation of 2 red, 3 green$)$ $=\frac{7\cdot6\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2}{11!\div6!}$. Then, there are many permutations of 2R3G. 4 ways the first red is the first draw, 3 ways it's the second draw, 2 ways it's the third draw, and 1 way it's the fourth draw. $4+3+2+1$ $=10$ total permutations. So $P(\text{2 red})$ should be $10\cdot\frac{7\cdot6\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2}{11!\div6!}$ $=\frac{2}{11}$.

There should be $10$ permutations of 3R2G (same math, except imagine ways to get 2G instead of 2R), which means $P(\text{3 red})$ $=10\cdot\frac{7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3}{11!\div6!}$ $=\frac{5}{11}$.

Recap: $P(0\text{ red})$ $=0$, $P(1 \text{ red})$ $=\frac{1}{66}$, $P(2 \text{ red})$ $=\frac{2}{11}$, $P(3 \text{ red})$ $=\frac{5}{11}$, $P(4 \text{ red})$ $=\frac{10}{33}$, $P(5 \text{ red})$ $=\frac{1}{22}$. $P(\text{total})$ $=0$ $+\frac{1}{66}$ $+\frac{2}{11}$ $+\frac{5}{11}$ $+\frac{10}{33}$ $+\frac{1}{22}$ $=1$, which is good.

**Converting from Specific to General**

From this point, I can hopefully find a pattern of how to solve generic questions of this nature. Switching away from the nomenclature given in the title, I have
$T_R=$ total number of red balls $=7$,
$T_G=$ total number of green balls $=4$,
$T=$ total number of balls $=T_R+T_G$ $=11$,
$D_R=$ number of red balls drawn,
$D_G=$ number of green balls drawn, and
$D=$ total balls drawn $=D_R+D_G$ $=5$.

Some preliminaries. A) Since I only care about the number of red balls, the same solution should apply even if I had, for example, 7 red balls, 2 blue balls, 1 white ball and 1 green ball. So really, $D_G$ could be $D_B+D_W+D_G$ or whatever. Ultimately, it's just $D-D_R$. B) My results always end up in the form $P=C\cdot\frac{F_N}{F_D}$.

The first thing I notice is that my fraction's denominator is always the product $F_D=T\cdot(T-1)$ $\cdot\ldots$ $\cdot(T-D+1)$. This simplifies to $F_D=\frac{T!}{(T-D)!}$.

Next, I notice that my fraction's numerator is always the product $F_N=T_R\cdot(T_R-1)$ $\cdot\ldots$ $\cdot(T_R-D_R+1)$ $\cdot T_G$ $\cdot(T_G-1)$ $\cdot\ldots$ $\cdot(T_G-D_G+1)$. This simplifies to $F_N=\frac{T_R!T_G!}{(T_R-D_R)!(T_G-D_G)!}$. Noting that $T_G$ is just the count of not-red balls and $D_G$ is not-red balls drawn, we get $F_N=\frac{T_R!(T-T_R)!}{(T_R-D_R)!(T-T_R-(D-D_R))!}$ $=\frac{T_R!(T-T_R)!}{(T_R-D_R)!(T-T_R-D+D_R)!}$.

Finally, I note that I have a coefficient equal to the number of permutations of $D_R$ red balls and $D_G$ not-red balls. Looking through my book, I have an equation for "permutations of *n* things, divided into *c* classes of alike things differing from class to class", where $\text{permutations}$ $=\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!\cdots n_c!}$. In my case, $n=D$, $n_1$ $=D_R$, and $n_2$ $=n_c$ $=D-D_R$. Which leads to $C=$ $\frac{D!}{D_R!(D-D_R)!}$.

Putting all of this together, I get:

$P=\frac{D!}{D_R!(D-D_R)!}\cdot\frac{\frac{T_R!(T-T_R)!}{(T_R-D_R)!(T-T_R-D+D_R)!}}{\frac{T!}{(T-D)!}}$ $=\frac{D!T_R!(T-T_R)!(T-D)!}{D_R!(D-D_R)!(T_R-D_R)!(T-T_R-D+D_R)!T!}$

I'm not sure if there's a way to simplify that further, but if everything is accurate, I can just plug in the four values in the question (well, noting that $D=D_R+D_G$) and get an answer.

Plugging this into WolframAlpha using the given constants, I get:
$P(0)=$ [$0$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d!*r!*(t-r)!*(t-d)!%2F(x!*(d-x)!*(r-x)!*(t-r-d%2Bx)!*t!),+where+d%3D5,+x%3D0,+t%3D11,+r%3D7)
$P(1)=$ [$\frac{1}{66}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d!*r!*(t-r)!*(t-d)!%2F(x!*(d-x)!*(r-x)!*(t-r-d%2Bx)!*t!),+where+d%3D5,+x%3D1,+t%3D11,+r%3D7)
$P(2)=$ [$\frac{2}{11}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d!*r!*(t-r)!*(t-d)!%2F(x!*(d-x)!*(r-x)!*(t-r-d%2Bx)!*t!),+where+d%3D5,+x%3D2,+t%3D11,+r%3D7)
$P(3)=$ [$\frac{5}{11}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d!*r!*(t-r)!*(t-d)!%2F(x!*(d-x)!*(r-x)!*(t-r-d%2Bx)!*t!),+where+d%3D5,+x%3D3,+t%3D11,+r%3D7)
$P(4)=$ [$\frac{10}{33}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d!*r!*(t-r)!*(t-d)!%2F(x!*(d-x)!*(r-x)!*(t-r-d%2Bx)!*t!),+where+d%3D5,+x%3D4,+t%3D11,+r%3D7)
$P(5)=$ [$\frac{1}{22}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d!*r!*(t-r)!*(t-d)!%2F(x!*(d-x)!*(r-x)!*(t-r-d%2Bx)!*t!),+where+d%3D5,+x%3D5,+t%3D11,+r%3D7)
(To get it to work on WolframAlpha, I substituted $d=D$, $x=D_R$, $t=T$, $r=T_R$.)

Since these are the numbers I got earlier, this is promising.

**Converting to "n choose k" Format**

Looking through my book, there's a formula for combinations. Specifically, combinations of *n* different things, taken *k* at a time, without repetitions, is $\text{combinations}$ $=\binom{\color{magenta}{n}}{\color{green}{k}}$ $=\frac{\color{magenta}{n}!}{\color{green}{k}!(\color{magenta}{n}-\color{green}{k})!}$.

I notice the formula I came up with looks a lot like the factorials in the combinations formula. So I'm hoping there's a way to simplify my formula so it uses $\binom{n}{k}$ functions instead of explicit factorials. The first two lines are color-coded so you can see how I moved from one line to the next.

$P=\frac{\color{blue}{D!}T_R!\color{orange}{(T-T_R)!}\color{blue}{(T-D)!}}{D_R!\color{orange}{(D-D_R)!}(T_R-D_R)!\color{orange}{(T-T_R-D+D_R)!}\color{blue}{T!}}$

$P$ $=\color{blue}{\frac{D!(T-D)!}{T!}}$ $\color{orange}{\frac{(T-T_R)!}{(D-D_R)!((T-T_R)-(D-D_R))!}}$ $\frac{T_R!}{D_R!(T_R-D_R)!}$

Now, color code it according to the combination definition above.

$P$ $=\frac{\color{green}{D}!(\color{magenta}{T}-\color{green}{D})!}{\color{magenta}{T}!}$ $\frac{\color{magenta}{(T-T_R)}!}{\color{green}{(D-D_R)}!(\color{magenta}{(T-T_R)}-\color{green}{(D-D_R)})!}$ $\frac{\color{magenta}{T_R}!}{\color{green}{D_R}!(\color{magenta}{T_R}-\color{green}{D_R})!}$

Seems pretty straightforward to convert this to $\binom{n}{k}$.

$P$ $=\frac{\frac{\color{magenta}{(T-T_R)}!}{\color{green}{(D-D_R)}!(\color{magenta}{(T-T_R)}-\color{green}{(D-D_R)})!} \frac{\color{magenta}{T_R}!}{\color{green}{D_R}!(\color{magenta}{T_R}-\color{green}{D_R})!}}{\frac{\color{green}{D}!(\color{magenta}{T}-\color{green}{D})!}{\color{magenta}{T}!}}$

$P$ $=\frac{\color{orange}{\binom{T-T_R}{D-D_R}}\binom{T_R}{D_R}}{\color{blue}{\binom{T}{D}}}$

Checking with WolframAlpha:

$P(0)=$ [$0$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(binomial(t-r,+d-x)*binomial(r,+x))%2Fbinomial(t,+d),+where+d%3D5,+x%3D0,+t%3D11,+r%3D7)
$P(1)=$ [$\frac{1}{66}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(binomial(t-r,+d-x)*binomial(r,+x))%2Fbinomial(t,+d),+where+d%3D5,+x%3D1,+t%3D11,+r%3D7)
$P(2)=$ [$\frac{2}{11}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(binomial(t-r,+d-x)*binomial(r,+x))%2Fbinomial(t,+d),+where+d%3D5,+x%3D2,+t%3D11,+r%3D7)
$P(3)=$ [$\frac{5}{11}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(binomial(t-r,+d-x)*binomial(r,+x))%2Fbinomial(t,+d),+where+d%3D5,+x%3D3,+t%3D11,+r%3D7)
$P(4)=$ [$\frac{10}{33}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(binomial(t-r,+d-x)*binomial(r,+x))%2Fbinomial(t,+d),+where+d%3D5,+x%3D4,+t%3D11,+r%3D7)
$P(5)=$ [$\frac{1}{22}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(binomial(t-r,+d-x)*binomial(r,+x))%2Fbinomial(t,+d),+where+d%3D5,+x%3D5,+t%3D11,+r%3D7)

Again, this matches what I got by hand.

**Actual Questions**

Is my math correct? Is the final answer something I can actually use for other problems of this type, or did I just happen to get a good result because I tested it against the same problem I formulated the answer with? Are there limiting factors here? Is there an easier way to get the same result?

Comment: Checkout Hypergeometric Distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Yeap.   That's okay.

You took the long, winding road to get to your destination, but enjoyed the scenery, and learned something along the way.

It's all good.

---

The easier way to get to the result is to just use the combinatorial definition of the binomial coefficient and go straight to goal.   $\binom n r$ counts the ways to select $r$ elements from $n$.

Out of all the (equally-probable) ways to select $D$ from $T$ balls, we wish to know the probability for selecting $D_R$ from $T_R$ red balls and $D-D_R$ from $T-T_R$ remaining.

$$\mathsf P(X=D) ~=~ \dfrac{\dbinom{T_R}{D_R}\dbinom{T-T_R}{D-D_R}}{\dbinom{T}{D}}$$

Then you just have to note what values of $D$ give non-zero probability (the support of the probability mass function).

That is all.

---

> Probability of X red balls when drawing Y balls from A red and B green balls.

$$\mathsf P(X=x) ~=~ \dfrac{\dbinom A x~\dbinom B{Y-x}}{\dbinom {A+B}Y} \quad\mathbf 1_{x\in\bigl[\max\{0, B-Y\};\min\{A,Y\}\bigr]\cap\Bbb N}$$